# Open URLS from list and write data

Tags: python, url, screen-scraping, bigdata, urllib

I am writing a code which creates several URLs, which again are stored in a list.
The next step would be, open each URL, download the data (which is only text, formatted in XML or JSON) and save the downloaded data.

My code works fine thanks to the online community here up. It stuck at the point to open the URL and download the data. I want the url.request to loop through the list with my created urls and call each url seperately, open it, display it and move on to the next. But it only does the loop to create the urls, but then nothing. No feedback, nothing.

```
import urllib.request

.... some calculations for llong and llat ....


#create the URLs and store in list
urls = []
for lat,long,lat1,long1 in (zip(llat, llong,llat[1:],llong[1:])):
    for pages in range (1,17):
        print ("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&api_key=5.b&nojsoncallback=1&page={}&per_page=250&bbox={},{},{},{}&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description".format(pages,long,lat,long1,lat1))
print (urls)


#accessing the website 
data = []
for amounts in urls:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(urls)
    flickrapi = data.read()
    data.append(+flickrapi)
    data.close()
    print (data)
```

What am I doing wrong`?

The next step would be, downloading the data and save them to a file or somewhere else for further processing.
Since I will receive heaps of data, like a lot lot lot, I am not sure what would be the best way to store it to precess it with R (or maybe Python? - need to do some statistical work on it). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not appending your generated urls to the url list, you are printing them:

```
print ("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&api_key=5.b&nojsoncallback=1&page={}&per_page=250&bbox={},{},{},{}&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description".format(pages,long,lat,long1,lat1))
```

Should be:

```
urls.append("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&api_key=5.b&nojsoncallback=1&page={}&per_page=250&bbox={},{},{},{}&accuracy=1&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags,views,description".format(pages,long,lat,long1,lat1))
```

Then you can iterate over the urls as planned.

But you'll run into the error on the following line:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(urls)
```

Here you are feeding the whole set of urls into `urlopen`, where you should be passing in a single url from urls which you have named `amounts` like so:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(amounts)
```

Comment: Doing this, thats the feedback I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christoph/Desktop/test.py", line 54, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(urls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 156, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 460, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'`

Comment: ah, awesome! next step is downloading the data. thanks!